# Transposing Excel columns into rows based on id numbers using Perl

Tags: perl, excel

Hi I am fairly new to Perl and been asked to do a task.

I have a record file in .csv format with 10 or more files and been asked to transpose the records so each row is turned into 10 rows per records.

```
id Column1 column2 column3 ..... column N
1  apple   Red     Medium        Text1
2  Mango   Yellow  Large         Text2
3  Banana  Yellow  small         Text3
4  Apple   Red     Medium        Text4
5  Pear    Green   Medium        Text5
```

And this need to be displayed as

```
id 1 column1   Apple
id 1 column2   Red
id 1 column3   Medium
.
.
id 1 columnN   text1
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? use  Text::CSV. You have to apply some math, to accommodate your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As @aartist commented, all you need is [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV). You can install it with `cpan` utility or with this oneliner:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo Text::CSV
```

Please read documentation, your task should be solved very easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Per additional input it looks like kind-of interleaved header columns are needed:

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => ';' })
    or die;

my $hdr = $csv->getline(\*DATA);
while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    $csv->combine(
        map { $hdr->[0], $row->[0], $hdr->[$_], $row->[$_] } 1..$#$row
    );
    print $csv->string,"\n";
}

__DATA__
id;Column1;column2;column3;columnN
1;apple;Red;Medium;Text1
2;Mango;Yellow;Large;Text2
3;Banana;Yellow;small;Text3
4;Apple;Red;Medium;Text4
5;Pear;Green;Medium;Text5
```

This gives:

```
id;1;Column1;apple;id;1;column2;Red;id;1;column3;Medium;id;1;columnN;Text1
id;2;Column1;Mango;id;2;column2;Yellow;id;2;column3;Large;id;2;columnN;Text2
id;3;Column1;Banana;id;3;column2;Yellow;id;3;column3;small;id;3;columnN;Text3
id;4;Column1;Apple;id;4;column2;Red;id;4;column3;Medium;id;4;columnN;Text4
id;5;Column1;Pear;id;5;column2;Green;id;5;column3;Medium;id;5;columnN;Text5
```

Comment: My Apologies for not being clear. This is exactly what I need but I need this transposed in the card format so there whole set of data in column now coming as row. I have tried to paint the format as below. 
For first record it will look like 
ID 1 Column1 Apple
ID 1 Column2 Red
ID 1 Column3 Medium
.
.
ID 1 ColumnN Text1
Then for the next id I will have the same
ID 2 Column1 Mango
ID 2 Column2 Yellow
ID 2 Column3 Large
.
.
ID 2 ColumnN Text2
And this goes in the same format for all the ids in the .csv file
Once again your comments and guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: @Ace - so just interleave data with header?